# How to check if element is fully uncovered

Tags: cypress, visibility

This is NOT the common cypress issue where you get a test failure because a fixed element is covered by another element.

I have an expandable list toward the top of my page. When it expands, I want it to be on top of every other aspect of the page. So I'm writing a cypress test to verify that nothing else is covering it.

Unfortunately, the test isn't failing in a clear failure case.

[image]

This test is succeeding for the above list

```js
cy.get('#list')
  .should('be.visible')
  .find('p').each(($listItem) => {
    cy.wrap($listItem)
      .should('be.visible')
      .click(); // another layer of cover check
  });
```

I imagine this is succeeding because the elements aren't *hidden* and thus are 'visible,' and the click is succeeding because the center of each element is uncovered. How can I test that the list body is fully uncovered/displaying on top?

Answer (score 1):

In the image the list is right-ish of the dropdown, so this is one way to check for overlap in the x-dimension:

```js
cy.get('#dropdown').then($el => {
    const rhs = Math.round($el[0].getBoundingClientRect().right)

    cy.get('#list').then($el => {
      const lhs = Math.round($el[0].getBoundingClientRect().left)
      expect(lhs).to.be.gt(rhs)
    })
  })
```

It looks like there's also a table on the page which you'd want to repeat the check for.

To generalize a little bit:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('hasNoOverlapWith', {prevSubject: true}, (subject, others) => {
  let covered = false;
  const targetRect = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect()
  others.forEach(other => {
    cy.get(other).then($el => {
      const otherRect = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect()

      // other covers from the left
      const coveredLeft = otherRect.right >= targetRect.left && 
        otherRect.right <= targetRect.right

      // other covers from the right
      const coveredRight = otherRect.left <= targetRect.right && 
        otherRect.left >= targetRect.left

      if (!covered) {
        covered = coveredLeft || coveredRight
      }
    })
  })

  cy.then(() => {
    expect(covered).to.eq(false)
  })
})

cy.get('#list').hasNoOverlapWith(['#dropdown', '#table'])
```

Comment: Weird that cypress doesn't seem to have something akin to `.should('not.be.covered')` or something built in. Is this not a common thing to check for?

Comment: Indeed. Should also consider `z-index` in the equation. The elements may overlap, but if `#list` has the highest `z-index` it would not be covered.